# Finding the size of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

The idea of the program is to input elements in an array. Then give the integer 'x' a value. If 'x' is 3 and the array a[] holds the elements {1,2,3,4,5,6}, we must "split" a[] into two other arrays. Lets say b[] and c[].
In b[] we must put all values lower or equal to 3 and in c[] all values greater than 3.

My question is-  How can i express the 3 elements in b[i]?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[6];
    int b[6];
    int c[6];
    int d;


    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];

    }
    cin >> d;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

        if (d >= a[i]) {
            b[i] = a[i]; // if d is 3, then i have 3 elements. How can i express them?
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if (d< a[i]) {
            c[i] = a[i];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << b[i];
    }

    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 3; i < 6; i++) {
        cout << c[i];
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You mean you want something like `std::vector`?

Comment: We haven't studied vectors yet.  I know that c[i] = 4,5,6 and b[i]=1,2,3 , if d =3. They both hold 3 elements, but i have no clue how  i can express that.

Comment: if you are learning c-arrays before learning vectors, you are not learning c++. Please dont trust your teachers and read about vectors.

Comment: If you don't follow Mike's advice you have two traditional ways. (1) You have a separate int storing the number of valid elements in each array. (That is what vector does, internally.) (2) You determine one value which cannot naturally occur in the data (say, `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`), and use it as an end marker in the array. Both methods are used in communicating the number of elements in the `argv[]` parameter to`main()`, and the 0 byte as an "unnatural value" is used in C style character strings to signal the end of the valid data.

Comment: Let's start from the obvious. If `a` is `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`, one array has the first three elements set and the other array has the *last* three elements set, It `a` is `{1,4,2,5,3,6}`, one array has the *even-numbered* elements set and the other one has the *odd-numbered* elements set. You don't want that. Change your code so that whatever `a` is, both `b` and `c` have their *initial* elements set. Then it will become more apparent how to express what you want.

Comment: I'm not clear what everyone else is yammering about. From what I see you appear to need a pair of additional counters to use when populating your over-under arrays, which are conveniently already sized to their  maximum *potential* usage. As you select elements for a given array, copy it over from `a[]` and bump the target array's counter.

Comment: I second @WhozCraig. For ordered data (as in your example) you need at least one more int to store the transition index to numbers >d; if the data is unordered, you'll want to store all small numbers in `b` starting at index 0 (and keep track of the number stored in a seaparate counter/index); likewise for `c`(`c[0]` would hold the first number encountered larger than `d`; that can be at an arbitrary index in `a`.)

Comment: @specbk, I'd recommend thinking about how you can condense your code to avoid having to iterate over the array twice at the beginning to populate `b[]` and `c[]`. You guys have learned about `if` statements already, so I'm sure you also learned about the `else` block that can go along with it. It'd probably be a good exercise for you, if nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! About a week ago i bought "Principles and Practice Using C++ (Second Edition)" and i saw that there is a lot of information and exercies about vectors. After i finish reading about them i will give it another try.

Answer (score 2):

I think all you're trying to do is have a way to determine how many `int` values you're copying from `a[]` to either `b[]` or `c[]`. To do that, introduce two more counters that start at zero and increment with each item copied to the associated array:

Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[6];
    int b[6], b_count=0; // see here
    int c[6], c_count=0; // see here
    int d;


    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];

    }
    cin >> d;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

        if (d >= a[i]) {
            b[b_count++] = a[i]; // see here
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if (d< a[i]) {
            c[c_count++] = a[i]; // see here
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < b_count; i++) { // see here
        cout << b[i];
    }

    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 3; i < c_count; i++) { // and finally here
        cout << c[i];
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Now, if you want `b[]` or `c[]` to be *dynamic* in their space allocation, then dynamic-managed containers like `st::vector<>` would be useful, but I don't think that is required for this *specific* task. Your `b[]` and `c[]` are already large enough to hold *all* elements from `a[]` if needed.

Comment: Why not to join 2 loops into one with else statement?

Comment: @Slava Because that wasn't what the question was about. This guy is green as grass; the lest he has to absorb the better.

Comment: one loop would clearly implement the intention - copy a[] to either b[] or c[] - that makes code cleaner and easier to understand. It should be at least mentioned.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had no clue that i can use a counter in such a way. @Slava i will try it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

WhozCraigs answer does a good job showing what you need to solve this using traditional arrays according to your tasks requirements.

I'd just like to show you how this can be done if you were allowed the full arsenal of the standard library. It is why people are calling for you to use std::vector. Things gets simpler that way.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a[6] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }; // Not using input for brevity.
    int x = 3; // No input, for brevity

    // Lets use the std:: instead of primitives
    auto first_part = std::begin(a);
    auto last = std::end(a);

    auto comparison = [x](int e){ return e <= x; };
    auto second_part = std::partition(first_part, last, comparison);

    // Print the second part. 
    std::for_each(second_part, last, [](int e){ std::cout << e; });

    // The first part is first_part -> second_part
}
```

The partition function does exactly what your problem is asking you to solve, but it does it inside of the array `a`. The returned value is the first element in the second part.

Comment: for full arsenal of standard library you should use `std::begin(a)` and `std::end(a)`, not magic numbers

Comment: @Slava Indeed I do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use `std::vectors`. do not use `int[]`s.

with `int[]`s (that are pre-c++11) you could, with a few heavy assumptions, find array length with `sizeof(X)/sizeof(X[0])`; This has, however, never been a good practice.

in the example you provided, probably you wanted to:

```
    #define MAX_LEN 100
    ...
    int main() {
       int a[MAX_LEN];
       int b[MAX_LEN];
       int c[MAX_LEN];
       int n;
       std::cout << "how many elements do you want to read?" << std::endl;
       std::cin >> n;
```

and use `n` from there on (these are common practice in programming schools)

Consider a function that reads a vector of ints:

```
std::vector<int> readVector() {
    int n;
    std::cout << "how many elements do you want to read?" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> n;

    std::vector<int> ret;

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        std::cout << "please enter element " << (i+1) << std::endl;
        int el;
        std::cin >> el;
        ret.push_back(el);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

you could use, in main, `auto a = readVector(); auto b = readVector();` `a.size()` would be the length, and would allow to keep any number of ints

Comment: I think we're all in agreement that vectors are a better C++ solution than arrays, but the question asks specifically about arrays. It makes no mention of vectors

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you'll approach it once you've a little more experience.

Anything you don't understand in here is worth studying [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

std::vector<int> get_inputs(std::istream& is)
{
    std::vector<int> result;
    int i;
    while(result.size() < 6 && is >> i) {
        result.push_back(i);
    }
    return result;
}

std::pair<std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>>
split_vector(const std::vector<int>& src, int target)
{
    auto it = std::find(src.begin(), src.end(), target);
    if (it != src.end()) {
        std::advance(it, 1);
    }
    return std::make_pair(std::vector<int>(src.begin(), it),
                          std::vector<int>(it, src.end()));
}

void print_vector(const std::vector<int>& vec)
{
    auto sep = " ";
    std::cout << "[";
    for (auto i : vec) {
        std::cout << sep << i;
        sep = ", ";
    }
    std::cout << " ]" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    auto initial_vector = get_inputs(std::cin);
    int pivot;
    if(std::cin >> pivot)
    {
        auto results = split_vector(initial_vector, pivot);
        print_vector(results.first);
        print_vector(results.second);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "not enough data";
        return 1;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

example input:
    1 2 3 4 5 6
    3

expected output:

```
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
[ 4, 5, 6 ]
```

Comment: I will give it a try when i finish reading about vectors, thanks a lot!